# NavigationView inside NavigationView SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

How can I remove navigationBar inside navigationView.When I use navigate view inside another navigationview it show me another navigationbar and put space from navigationBar.How can I solve this problem . I tried to use navigationBarHidden or NavigationBarTitle (displaymode : .inline) but it didn't work.Its works when I use for one NavigationView but inside another navigationView its not working.

```
struct ShowCaseView : View {
    
    var productList = ShowCaseViewModel()
    
    @State var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @State var productListData : ShowCaseDataResponse?
    @State var isAnimating : Bool = true
    @State var showCaseData : [ShowCaseData] = []
    @State var isOpened : Bool = true
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            NavigationView{
            
            ScrollView {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    if productListData?.success == true {
                        
                        ForEach(showCaseData , id:\.id) { data in
                            
                            if data.isHeaderVisible == true {
                                
                                Text(data.name ?? "")
                                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                                    .bold()
                                
                            }
                            ListTypeShow(data: data)
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            }.navigationBarTitle("",displayMode: .inline)
            ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: $isAnimating)
        }
        
        
        .onAppear {
            
            if isOpened == true {
                
                getStoreIndex()
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you need two NavigationView/s? Not sure if it is designed for that - I met reporting many issues for such case (even if you'll got fixed this one). I recommend to use only one NavigationView in same view hierarchy, as it is designed.

Comment: Actually im using one navigaitonView in same View. But the problem is I navigate this view from another view so that's the reason it show me navigationbar so when I tried to use another NavigationView inside this view its take like 2 navigationbar space. The reason im using navigationView its easy to control because I have so many navigation . But if there is another way to do without using navigationView I can use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If parent view of `ShowCaseView` already has `NavigationView` then you don't need another one in `ShowCaseView`, ie.

```
struct ShowCaseView : View {
    
    var productList = ShowCaseViewModel()
    
    @State var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @State var productListData : ShowCaseDataResponse?
    @State var isAnimating : Bool = true
    @State var showCaseData : [ShowCaseData] = []
    @State var isOpened : Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
//            NavigationView{       // << remove this one !!
```

Comment: How I couldn't think this :) . Yeah its inside NavigationView. thank you it worked.